# Pixel perfect, sharp uv mapping

Tags: blender

I'm having trouble understanding how the uv map that Blender gives you works. It gives you a map with outlines which you should color in. But if I have a low-res texture I don't know where should I color in exactly. Should I place my textures between the outlines, or should my textures overlap the outlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the uv seams as borders to what is drawn on the assigned polygon/triangle.

The uv map has no impact on where you can draw (except for blenders texture-paint feature),
it only shows you what part of the texture-image the polygons display.

You should definitely make your pixels overlap the uv seams (the more the better) or else you will see visual artifacts where the uv seams are.
These artifacts will become stronger as you move the camera away from the model.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, can you also check this out? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67003/why-does-my-model-render-like-this

Comment: had a look at it but, well, i'm a 3d-modeller, not an opengl programmer ;( you could paste the critical code in that topic if its not going forward.